# Anydesk zsh error in kali linux

Tags: zsh, kali-linux, anydesk

In my kali linux while trying to access anydesk it is showing following error

```
└─$ anydesk
zsh: abort      anydesk
```

Comment: Anydesk is a remote access application. Kali is a penetration tester's toolbox, and pentesting is an onsite hands-on job, not something you do via remote access. Because of it's special nature security is crucial in Kali, so a many things which are normal in a desktop environment (like remote access using a random application) is by default prevented. You should get familiar with [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/) so you have a better understanding of it. A better idea is to install AnyDesk on your host OS; then you can use Kali VM the same way you would sitting at the computer.

Answer (score 1):

That's `zsh` telling you the process in which it had started the `anydesk` command has died of a SIGABRT signal.

That signal is generally delivered via the `abort()` standard function.

That function is typically used by applications or libraries used by applications when they detect some abnormal condition likely  caused by some bug and need to abort and tell the caller so.

Unless a core dump size limit has been set to 0, a dump of the memory image (`core` dump) is also made on disk which can help a developer investigate the problem further. As the message by `zsh` doesn't include `(core dumped)`, the limit has probably  been set  (see output of `limit coredumpsize`).

Log files for your software or the system may give you more indication as to the cause of the `abort()`.